# MySQL boolean full text search not working as expected

Tags: mysql

I have a table of chemical substances, called `substances`. I'm trying to impelement a search facility making use of MySQL's [full text natural language](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-natural-language.html) capabilities.

I have run the following to allow such commands to work on my `substances` table on the `name` column:

```
ALTER TABLE substances ADD FULLTEXT(`name`);
```

If I run the following command it gives me any results which contain either the word "Chromium" or "Trioxide" as expected:

```
SELECT * FROM substances WHERE MATCH (`name`) AGAINST ('Chromium Trioxide' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

However what I want to do is find only rows that contain "Chromium Trioxide", even if there are characters in between them (e.g. "Chromium (VI) Trioxide"). My understanding is that using a `+` before each word would do this:

```
SELECT * FROM substances WHERE MATCH (`name`) AGAINST ('+Chromium +Trioxide' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

But it gives me the same results as the original query - i.e. anything that contains either "Chromium" or "Trioxide" but not both.

Where am I going wrong?  I've read up on Boolean Full Text searches (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html) but the only info I found was to include the `+` before each keyword.

MySQL version is 5.7.9 and the table is MyISAM.

Comment: While you basically read correctly, to use the boolean mode (that supports modifiers like `+`) you have to write `IN BOOLEAN MODE` instead of `IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how solve it using mysql boolean full-text search or natural full-text search,

but i think that can be done using REGEX (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html)

```
SELECT * FROM substances WHERE `name` REGEXP 'Chromium .* Trioxide'
```